# Uncountable Intersection and Union of Open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $I = (0,\infty)$, and let $A_x := (0,x)$.

> Prove: (i) $\bigcap_{x \in I}A_x = \phi$ (the empty set) and (ii) $\bigcup_{x \in I}A_x = I$

If we consider a decreasing sequence $\{1/n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$, and define $B_n := (0,1/n)$, it is intuitively clear that the sequence of sets $\{\bigcap_{i = 1}^n B_i \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ is decreasing i.e. $B_{k+1} \subset B_k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, so the intersection $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} B_n = \phi$.

Similarly, if we have an increasing sequence $\{n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ and define $C_n := (0,n)$, it is clear that the sequence of sets $\{\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ increases without bound, and so $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} C_n = (0,\infty)$.

But how do we prove this rigorously, using only basic set theory, for (i) and (ii) above?

Thanks.

Comment: Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. Can you find some $x$ such that $\alpha \notin x$? If so, then $\alpha$ can't be in the intersection. For the union think along the same lines. Isn't any positive real in *some* interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $A_x \subset I$ for each $x$, we know that $\bigcap_{x\in I}{A_x} \subset I$.  Suppose $x\in \bigcap_{x\in I}{A_x}$.  Then $0<x<I$, but $x\notin A_y$ for $y<x$, so we reach a contradiction.

Likewise, if $x\in (0,\infty)$, then $x\in A_{x+1}$, so $x\in \bigcup_{x\in I}{A_x}$.